# Image from Another Entry

Tags: entries, image, set

Is it possible to pull an image from another entry? It seems like it would be simple. I've read a lot of posts and documentation, and feel like I'm close...

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.slug('homepage') %}

{% for image in entry.podcastItunesImage %}
    <itunes:image href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ image.getUrl}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, I'm trying to put an asset field on the Homepage for a iTunes image.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think you are close, you've just go your variables a bit mixed up. You set `entries`, but then reference `entry` and I think `getUrl` should be called as a function `getUrl()` as it's not a property (it might work that way, I've never tried tbh)

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug('homepage') %}

{% for image in entry.podcastItunesImage %}
 <itunes:image href="{{ image.first.getUrl() }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**
Oh I don't think you need `{{ siteUrl }}` when you call `getUrl()`

Comment: You don't need `.getUrl()` either. `{{ image.url }}` would work aswell.

Comment: Oh nice, good tip!

Comment: That didn't work. The results are empty. I may end up creating a template file just for the podcast, so I can have a little more control over it.

Comment: You probably need to do `{{ image.first.url }}` because image fields can hold multiple images.